# iPhone : Does AVAudioPlayer supports .wav format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, avaudioplayer

I am going to use .wav audio files in my app.

Does `AVAudioPlayer` supports `.wav` file format ?

And which other formats supported by `AVAudioPlayer` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) gives you the possibility to play `.wav` files.

It's pretty straight forward:

```
// in the corresponding .h file:
// @property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;

// in the .m file:
@synthesize player; // the player object

NSString *soundFilePath =
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"sound"
                                            ofType: @"wav"];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer =
            [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL
                                                   error: nil];
[fileURL release];

self.player = newPlayer;
[newPlayer release];

[player prepareToPlay];
```

From: [Playing Sounds Easily with the AVAudioPlayer Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6)

Answer (score 1):

You find complete answer on your question here : [MultimediaPG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html)

Audio Playback and Recording Formats
The audio playback formats supported in iPhone OS are the following:

```
*AAC
*HE-AAC
*AMR (Adaptive Multi-Rate, a format for speech)
*ALAC (Apple Lossless)
*iLBC (internet Low Bitrate Codec, another format for speech)
*IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
*linear PCM (uncompressed)
*µ-law and a-law
*MP3 (MPEG-1 audio layer 3
```

The audio recording formats supported in iPhone OS are the following:

```
*AAC (on supported devices only)
*ALAC (Apple Lossless)
*iLBC (internet Low Bitrate Codec, for speech)
*IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
*linear PCM
*µ-law and a-law
```